# Training my fingers

Tags: key-bindings

Emacs, like any Great Thing, is a journey.

First you start with learning to use <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> (or <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> in `evil`) instead of the up and down arrows; then you need to progress to using searches and other more advanced motions.

But you have a problem: your fingers are stuck in their old, inefficient ways! There is a solution though: to ‘undefine’ the more basic key sequences to something *really, really annoying!*

**To what intolerably annoying function would you suggest redefining these basic key sequences?** (In order to kick the habit of using them too much?)

(You might include: audio; freezing Emacs; an animation; or something more creative – or a combination of them all!)

Comment: @Drew; I feel this sort of format works OK with codegolf.se; I meant this as a kind of challenge, where the answers thought to be 'the best' by general consensus would be voted up . . . if this is unacceptable on this site, though, then close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly creative "don't do that" might be to start the tutorial (normally bound to <kbd>C-h t</kbd>), as a side benefit it might be useful to reference it at that point.  Similarly starting info (<kbd>C-h i</kbd>) is an idea.  If you want it to be really annoying start one of the hacks from the Other Amusements section of the manual, I particularly like `dissociated-press`, but the `doctor` may try to help.  YMMV. :-)